# Where or when to unsubscribe an attached property in a dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties

I want to create an attached property to have access to the SelectedItems of a listBox in my view model.

The most simple example about an attached property is  this (for a textBox, not lIstBox, but for a first learning I think it is enough):

```
public static bool GetAllowOnlyString(DependencyObject obj)  
{  
   return (bool)obj.GetValue(AllowOnlyStringProperty);  
}  
public static void SetAllowOnlyString(DependencyObject obj, bool value)  
{  
   obj.SetValue(AllowOnlyStringProperty, value);  
}  
// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for AllowOnlyString. This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...  
public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowOnlyStringProperty =  
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AllowOnlyString", typeof(bool),typeof(TextblockExtension), new PropertyMetadata(false, AllowOnlyString));  
private static void AllowOnlyString(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  
{  
   if (d is TextBox)  
   {  
      TextBox txtObj = (TextBox)d;  
      txtObj.TextChanged += (s, arg) =>  
      {  
         TextBox txt = s as TextBox;  
         if (!Regex.IsMatch(txt.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]*$"))  
         {  
            txtObj.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;  
            MessageBox.Show("Only letter allowed!");  
         }  
      };  
   }  
}
```

I can see that if the object it is TextBox, then it is subcribe to the event TextChanged to the method that process the text.

My doubt is that there is not an unsubcribe to the event when it is not needed.

In my case I will use the attached property in a dialog, so I will create my view, my viewModel and I will use the attached property that it will subscribe to the event, how ever, when I will close the dialog, the event is not unsubscribe.

Really I would see another example with a attached behavior, but for me it is a bit more complex, and really I don't know the difference between attached properties and attached behavior, so in this case i would like to learn to use the attached property.

Another example is this:

```
public class ListBoxSelectedItemsAttachedProperty
    {
        #region SelectedItems
        private static ListBox list;
        private static bool _isRegisteredSelectionChanged = false;

        ///
        /// SelectedItems Attached Dependency Property
        ///
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItems", typeof(IList),
        typeof(ListBoxSelectedItemsAttachedProperty),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault
            ,new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedItemsChanged)
            ));

        public static IList GetSelectedItems(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (IList)d.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSelectedItems(DependencyObject d, IList value)
        {
            d.SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_isRegisteredSelectionChanged)
            {
                ListBox listBox = (ListBox)d;
                list = listBox;
                listBox.SelectionChanged += listBox_SelectionChanged;
                _isRegisteredSelectionChanged = true;
            }
        }

        private static void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get list box's selected items.
            IEnumerable listBoxSelectedItems = list.SelectedItems;
            //Get list from model
            IList ModelSelectedItems = GetSelectedItems(list);

            //Update the model
            ModelSelectedItems.Clear();

            if (list.SelectedItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in list.SelectedItems)
                    ModelSelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
            SetSelectedItems(list, ModelSelectedItems);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

It works when I open the dialog first time, but if I close and the dialog and open again, it doesn't work because the static property isRegisteredSelectionChanged is true and then it will never subscribe the new dialog to the event.

Anyway in this case I have the same doubt, that I don't see when the event will be unsubscribe when I close the dialog.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dialog is removed after close, you can try a little hack:

```
private static void AllowOnlyString(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (d is TextBox)
    {
       TextBox txtObj = (TextBox)d;
       txtObj.TextChanged += Validation;
       txtObj.Unloaded += Unload;

     }
}

private static void Unload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var x = (TextBox)sender;
     x.Unloaded -= Unload;
     x.TextChanged -= Validation;
}

private static void Validation(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{       
     TextBox txtObj = sender as TextBox;
     if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtObj.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]*$"))
     {
        txtObj.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        MessageBox.Show("Only letter allowed!");
     }

}
```